# Python: Using two variable strings as Regex.findall criteria

Tags: python, regex, scripting

What's up guys, I try to receive two strings, and try to find every text padded by the two strings.
For example:

```
Pattern_text = '\|\|####\|\|' #To be received from user
first_half= Pattern_text [0:len(Pattern_text )//2]  # to get left side of pattern \\##
second_half= Pattern_text [len(Pattern_text )//2:]  # to get right side of pattern ##\\
#Sample text
SEARCH_ME = r"BLABLABLA BLA ||##MATCH_ID_1548##|| BLA ||##MATCH_ID_3412##|| BLABLABLA"
#Trying to find all matches padded by the two halves
results = re.findall((first_half+ r'(.*?)'+second_half), SEARCH_ME)
print(results)
```

results is always empty in this case.
expected results should be a list whose elements are 'MATCH_ID_1548'and'MATCH_ID_3412'

What do you reckon I should do with those two string variables, knowing that I'm sure the regex of the concatenated string (first_half + '(.*?)' + second_half) works when hardcoded. But not in that format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Pattern_text = '\|\|####\|\|'` needs to be `txt_to_fluff = '\|\|####\|\|'` https://ideone.com/dMq2tj

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of what's working on my end. We would be able to help you a lot more if you provide a complete and reproducible example in the question.

```
import re

prefix = "prefix #"
suffix = "# suffix"

regex = fr"{prefix}(.*?){suffix}"  # Renders as "prefix #(.*?)# suffix"
test_string = "prefix #TEST STRING# suffix"

print(re.findall(regex, test_string))  # ['TEST STRING']
```

Comment: I've edited it to be reproducible. I think your solution works perfectly, but the thing is I'm working with Python 2.7, it returns a syntax error when using:
regex = fr"{prefix}(.*?){suffix}"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another way. It will also work on cases where your 4 digit match id scales to 5 digit or more.

```
import re

SEARCH_ME = r"BLABLABLA BLA ||##MATCH_ID_1548##|| BLA ||##MATCH_ID_3412343434##|| BLABLABLA"

print(re.findall(re.compile('(?:MATCH_ID_[0-9]{4,})'), SEARCH_ME))
```

Result:

```
['MATCH_ID_1548', 'MATCH_ID_3412343434']
```